# BindingResult isn't detecting annotation based constraints and errors

Tags: java, spring-mvc, annotations, validation

The validation errors don't show up for some reason. In fact, the binding result doesn't return any errors. My bean is as follows:

```
@NotBlank
@Size(min = 5, max = 20, message = "User ID must be 5 to 20 characters long.")
@Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", message = "User ID must be alphanumeric.")
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@NotBlank
@Size(min = 6, max = 20, message = "The password must be between 6 to 20 characters long.")
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

My controller class has the following variable:

```
private BeanValidator beanValidator = new BeanValidator(new AnnotationBeanValidationConfigurationLoader());
```

There is a method in the controller which handles the binding.

```
beanValidator.validate(userLogin, bindingResult);

if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
    return "/";
}
else 
    return "/homepage";
```

When I login using blank credentials for the values of username and password, the system logs in. Evidently, bindingResult isn't detecting any errors. Help?

Comment: What about using `@Valid` instead of validating by hand?

Comment: Yeah I tried that. Stumbled into some errors until I figured the correct implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I used `@Valid` instead of implementing my own validator. Also, the parameter has to be in the following order:

```
public String homepage(@ModelAttribute(value="userLogin") @Valid UserLogin userLogin, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {//your code}
```

Mind the order of the `@Valid` bean parameter and `BindingResult` parameter. `BindingResult` should be placed after `@Valid` parameter otherwise error will be displayed.